# Canonical URL Meta Tag for a View Page

Tags: views, meta-tags

I'm using the Meta Tags Module and it has been a solid way to add meta tags throughout the site - especially the increasingly important Canonical URL meta tag.

I'm having trouble adding the same tag to views connected to a static page.

How can I add a canonical URL to some views pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Drupal 7.x and the latest alpha version of the Meta Tags module, correct? They are still working out the views integration functionality for this module but there is a [sandbox project](http://drupal.org/sandbox/ribakker/1356928) for this issue called 'meta tag views'. In Drupal 6.x nodewords, this was easier to do based upon path by just adding a custom entry at: /admin/content/nodewords/meta-tags/custom/add.

In the meantime, you can try the [metatags_quick](http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) module which lets you assign meta tags to specific paths. You would need to add the 'canonical url' as a possible field but the interface is simple to use.